# No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present error, even after providing origin

Tags: c#, reactjs, cors

I get below error, even after having the specific origin set in the server. I would appreciate if you point me what else could be the issue. Thank you.

"Access to fetch at 'https://mydomain/app/api/no=1' from origin 'https://apptest.azurewebsites.net' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

Startup.cs

```
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
 {
         var ReactAppOrigins = new string[] { "https://apptest.azurewebsites.net" };

         services.AddCors(
                    o => o.AddPolicy("ReactWebApiCorsPolicy", builder =>
                    {
                        builder.WithOrigins(ReactAppOrigins)
                        .AllowAnyMethod()
                        .AllowAnyHeader()
                        .AllowCredentials();
                    }));
 }

 public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
 {
        // Enable CORS  
        app.UseCors("ReactWebApiCorsPolicy");
 }
```

Edited: This is my current order in configure.

```
        app.UseCors("ReactWebApiCorsPolicy");
        app.UseRouting();
        app.UseAuthorization();
```

Comment: Run this: az webapp cors add --resource-group myResourceGroup --name <app-name> --allowed-origins 'domain'

Comment: I do not have permission to run this on resource level. Will I be able to do this in my code level? or do you think IT help would be required. Thank you.

Comment: i've deleted my answer since you have edited the question and using correct order, also routing should be above cors [reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/?view=aspnetcore-7.0#middleware-order)